# What's the easiest way to populate a dataframe (which has all zeros) with values of 1s

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe

Suppose I started off with a dataframe with all zeros. What's a better way than the way below to populate certain rows and columns with 1s?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

X = np.zeros((14,11))
df = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=['A','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun','Yes','No','D'])
df.loc[0,'Mon'] = 1
df.loc[0,'Yes'] = 1
df.loc[1,'Mon'] = 1
df.loc[1,'No'] = 1

df.loc[2,'Tue'] = 1
df.loc[2,'Yes'] = 1
df.loc[3,'Tue'] = 1
df.loc[3,'No'] = 1

df.loc[4,'Wed'] = 1
df.loc[4,'Yes'] = 1
df.loc[5,'Wed'] = 1
df.loc[5,'No'] = 1

df.loc[6,'Thu'] = 1
df.loc[6,'Yes'] = 1
df.loc[7,'Thu'] = 1
df.loc[7,'No'] = 1

df.loc[8,'Fri'] = 1
df.loc[8,'Yes'] = 1
df.loc[9,'Fri'] = 1
df.loc[9,'No'] = 1

df.loc[10,'Sat'] = 1
df.loc[10,'Yes'] = 1
df.loc[11,'Sat'] = 1
df.loc[11,'No'] = 1

df.loc[12,'Sun'] = 1
df.loc[12,'Yes'] = 1
df.loc[13,'Sun'] = 1
df.loc[13,'No'] = 1
```

Output dataframe:
[image: zerosdf]

Comment: could you explain how many elements you want to change to 1?  Are they random values that are 1? or even easier can you make the whole column to 1? 
if you explain the pattern i can help :)

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: Apologies, I have made the dataframe clearer by replacing the B columns with days and C column with Yes and No. These columns are indicator/dummy variables. So for each day, I need one row for Yes and another row for No. Is there a better way in doing this rather than that big chuck of code?

Answer (score 1):

try variations of: df[['B1','B2']] = df[['B1','B2']] .replace(0, 1)

Comment: Thanks for your input!. I think I have narrowed it down to `df.loc[0,['Mon','Yes']] = 1` for the 1st row, `df.loc[1,['Mon','No']] = 1` for the 2nd row and so on..